# Screen tearing in mate with compiz, not screen tearing with KDE or Unity

Tags: kde, xfce, mate-desktop

All distro I tried with KDE solved my tearing problem. I would love to use KDE  up its too heavy on my pc. I usually use xfce, but mate is fine too. I would love to get either xfce or mate working without screen tearing. How hard can it be if there are other desktops that work just fine?

And by the way. I have a ATI readen HD 3400 which has no drivers from their site.